# Concat multiple dataframes by datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, concatenation

I need combine multiple dataframes by datetime as well:

df1:

| datetime | Sales_Hour_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-29 11:00:00 | 92 |
| 2022-04-29 12:00:00 | 17 |
| 2022-04-29 13:00:00 | 46 |

df2:

| datetime | Sales_15_minutes_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-04-29 11:15:00 | 10 |
| 2022-04-29 11:30:00 | 32 |
| 2022-04-29 11:45:00 | 50 |
| 2022-04-29 12:30:00 | 17 |
| 2022-04-29 13:15:00 | 41 |
| 2022-04-29 13:45:00 | 5 |

df_expected_result:

| datetime | Sales_Hour_value | Sales_15_minutes_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-29 11:00:00 | 92 | NaN |
| 2022-04-29 11:15:00 | NaN | 10 |
| 2022-04-29 11:30:00 | NaN | 32 |
| 2022-04-29 11:45:00 | NaN | 50 |
| 2022-04-29 12:00:00 | 17 | NaN |
| 2022-04-29 12:30:00 | NaN | 17 |
| 2022-04-29 13:00:00 | 46 | NaN |
| 2022-04-29 13:15:00 | NaN | 41 |
| 2022-04-29 13:45:00 | NaN | 5 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An outer join will return all records that have values in either the left or the right dataframe:

```py
pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    how="outer",
    on="datetime",
    sort=True
)
```

This page gives a beautiful overview of many methods for merging joining and concatting: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging

Comment: no problem... if this solved your issue you can accept the answer as a solution